# Dealing with null values in categorical string data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-cleaning, preprocessing, dataframe

Which of the following is a better approach in dealing with null values and why?

1. Fill the null values with the mode (most occurring value).
2. Consider the null itself as a category by converting it to a string.
3. Remove the records with the null value.
4. Predict it using another non-null columns.

**Edit**
P.S: I am work with the following dataset
https://data.ontario.ca/dataset/confirmed-positive-cases-of-covid-19-in-ontario

It is about the covid-19 cases in Ontario. In this dataset a string categorical column named "Case_AcquisitionInfo". It has some values with string "MISSING INFORMATION" so should I consider this null or consider this as a category.

Comment: I feel removing the null records might be helpful. Filling the null values with the most frequent observation might result in outliers. You can consider `Null` as a category if the feature permits it. Like for a variable `isSick`, you can have two values `Yes` or `No`. A value of `Null ` could make no sense.

Comment: More information about your problem might be helpful. In example, how many categories do you have? what is the ratio of the null records in the data?

Comment: Assume the ratio is very low, say <1% of total data, then should I delete those records, or fill with mode. Anyways for large ratios I prefer to drop the column itself.

Comment: You can simply try both, and inspect results to determine what method to use in final model.